# How to check iOS11 Screen Recording is On or Off?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

For detecting iOS11 screen recording feature On or Off I used isCaptured and UIScreenCapturedDidChange Notification.

When first time I Launch the App and On iOS11 built-in screen recording feature then it notifies the selector method with value True, but when I kill (terminate) my running App and Launch app again do the same procedure again then my selector method is not getting called.

Here is my code:

I add an Observer in ViewWillAppear() method:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIScreenCapturedDidChange, object: nil)
```

The selector method is as follows:

```
@objc
func handleNotification(notification:Notification){

    let isCaptured = UIScreen.main.isCaptured

    print("isCaptured value = \(isCaptured)")
}
```

In this case, I need to kill the app, clear the cache and again launch the app for getting screen recording event.

Please suggest what I can do here to detect recording event to protect my content from recording.

Comment: did u tried the `mirrored ` property on `UIScreen`?

Comment: Thank you, Yes, I tried mirrored property, But I want to get screen recording events only.

Answer (score 13):

**Swift 4**

**Add Observer**

```
UIScreen.main.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "captured", options: .new, context: nil)
```

**Receive changes**

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if (keyPath == "captured") {
        let isCaptured = UIScreen.main.isCaptured

        print(isCaptured)
    }
}
```

Comment: hi is there any simillar way to detect when user takes ScrrenShot.i know "UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot" but it fired after user taken ScreenShot.

Comment: @Bhavesh.iosDev any success with screenshot thing?

Comment: @AnkitKumarGupta no bro still not found any solution.

Comment: But there is api screenshield that do the same thing.thay also have app:confind

Comment: Okk bro.. let me know if you have any update on this.

Comment: Is this private?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw no

Comment: If Screen capturing is true, then I have to stop recording. Is it possible from my app? @dimohamdy

Answer (score 3):

I guess you can alway check this variable regardless of the notification

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let isCaptured = UIScreen.main.isCaptured
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, But I will try to find the event's when user On or Off screen recording.

Comment: I also added the KVO in "captured" property. But it works only first time but when I kill the App and Launch again then not getting events from isCaptured. Is there any need for clear cache memory?

Comment: like i said you DO NOT need to track events or notification or "when it changed the captured value".. you can just read the value anytime

Comment: Hi, yasirmturk in my project I want to know when user start screen recording, i.e my App is running and in between if user start screen recording in iOS11 then that time I want to know screen recording is On and take a particular action just like Netflix and Amazon Prime for preventing content from piracy.

Comment: this actually also detect when your phone is on AirPlay or connected to an external monitor... might not be the desired effect.

Comment: I have to stop recording. Is it possible from my app? @yasirmturk

Comment: @UmeshKumath did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

The feature is available on and above iOS11. Better keep it inside **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

Objective-C syntax

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: 
 (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    BOOL isCaptured = [[UIScreen mainScreen] isCaptured];
    if(isCaptured){
       // Do the action for hiding the screen recording
                  } 
   } else{
        // Fallback on earlier versions
         }
 return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@UmeshKumath this is easy when kill the app clear the cache and again launch the app for getting screen recording event you need to run the code in viewdidload just like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
UIScreen.main.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "some key", options: .new, context: nil)
    let isCaptured = UIScreen.main.isCaptured
    if isCaptured == true {
        // do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the way to detect if a screenshot has been taken

```
func detectScreenShot(action: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let mainQueue = OperationQueue.main
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.userDidTakeScreenshotNotification, object: nil, queue: mainQueue) { notification in
        // executes after screenshot
        action()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using combine, you can subscribe to the `isCaptured` property of `UIScreen` and it will give you both the capturing and non-capturing states when the user starts and completes recording:

```
private var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = []

UIScreen.main.publisher(for: \.isCaptured)
   .sink { isCaptured in
       // Your code
   }
   .store(in: &cancellables)
```