# Prevent manual screenshot in IOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, screenshot, blur

On iOS, my requirement is disallow user to take manual screenshot from my application, **either disallow or blur the captured screenshot**. How?

Comment: see this for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232701/how-to-check-ios11-screen-recording-is-on-or-off/54390165

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: I have called NSOperationQueue& NSNotificationCenter in both viewDidLoad &viewWillAppear . but log also not displayed after capturing screenshot

Comment: @Cœur That's not necessarily true, Apple can't provide an API for every possible thing. I agree that this is a horrible feature and shouldn't be added to any app, but that doesn't mean it's not allowed just because there is no API for it.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution is to simulate the iOS controls you have in your View using DRM'ed videos.

For each widget you need to create a video subclass that renders the widget, and apply DRM to the video.

You can try to do it yourself, or use a commercial solution such as the following:
https://screenshieldkit.com

Comment: +1 This is a really fascinating exploit of DRM. Do you know if certain native tap based things stop working when you're basically streaming your app to a view or can you pass through all taps no problem?

Comment: You are not streaming a complete app to a view. You are simulating a few widgets using on-the-fly calculated videos that mimic standard widgets.

Comment: @stipus have you tried this custom DRM solution to confirm that it works?

Comment: I didn't try it myself, but the commercial solution web site has links to apps that implement their custom controls.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but I don't recommend it because of the room for error. It was easier to do in the past, in iOS13 you will have to do it like this:

You will have to ask for the user's permission to read and edit their photo library, then you have a listener which is checking the number of photos in their library while they are using your app, if that number changes, they have just taken a screenshot (unless you allow other things in your app like tap and hold to save image, etc). When this happens, read said photo and apply a blur, then delete the photo from their library and save the blurred photos.

Warning: There are times where a user may get a photo while using your app that is not a screenshot (e.g. they received an airdrop) and you will now be tampering with their photos, which is very bad. To prevent this you may need to use key value pixel encoding on your screen at all times, for example the first 3 pixels of the screen are 3 very specific RGB values, that way if a new photo is detected and the first 3 pixels are those exact RGB values you know it's a screenshot of your app and not just another photo that was somehow saved while the user was using the app.

Comment: @trojanfoe I said I wouldn't recommend it, but it is the only way to accomplish it, and if his boss is requiring him to do it, that's how it has to be done.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't any regular solution to your problem!

You can do some tricks such as if you force the user to have their finger on the screen for the image to show then I don't think they can create screenshots. Because as soon as you press the home+lock keys to actually take the screenshot, the screen seems to behave as if there are no fingers touching it.

**BUT** what if the user takes a screenshot by `AssistiveTouch`?!

**OR** what do you want to do if user records screen and taking screenshot from the video?

I think it's better to change your strategy for example notify the owner of picture for taking screen shot by another one (like `SnappChat`)!